# How many solutions has the equation $\sin x= \frac{x}{100}$ ?

Tags: trigonometry

How many solutions has the equation $\sin x= \frac{x}{100}$ ?

Usually when I was asked to solve this type of problem, I would solve it graphically but this one seems to be trickier. It doesn't seem wise to put $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\frac{x}{100}$ in the same graph and then counting all the intersection points. 
What would be some algebraic methods to solve this?

Comment: $f(x) = 100\sin x - x$

Comment: only $0$ is a solution

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Are you [sure](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+(sin+x)+%3D%3D+x%2F100)?

Comment: okay got from Bernard's answer

Comment: Another illustration: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(sin+x)+-+x%2F100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outside of the interval $[-100, 100]$ there are no solutions.

$x = 100\;$ occurs close to the right end of the interval $[30 \pi, 32 \pi]$

$x = -100\;$ occurs close to the left end of the interval $[-32 \pi, -30 \pi]$

Each interval $[2n\pi, (2n+2)\pi]$ will have 2 solutions for $n = -32$ to $n = 30$ except $x = 0$ will get counted twice.

So there are $2*32-1 = 63\;$ solutions.

Comment: I agree that each interval $[2n\pi, (2n+2)\pi]$ will have 2 solutions. I don't understand how you got 59. Don't we have 32 intervals, so there should be $2*32-1=63$ solutions?

Comment: @Lucija97 - Yes I fixed it. Thanks..

Comment: @Lucija97 - Do you know that you could have edited my answer too?

Comment: No, I'm new here.

Comment: @Lucija97 - Well I'm not and it seems I can't count.

Answer (score 5):

First, we may suppose $x\ge 0$ since both sides are odd functions.

Using the *Intermediate value theorem*, there'll be two non-negative solutions on each interval $]2k\pi,2(k+1)\pi[$ as long as $\frac x{100}\le 1$, i.e. $x\le 100$. There results the number of non-negative solutions is equal to $2\times \biggl\lfloor \dfrac{50}{\pi}\biggr\rfloor=32$.

Hence, by symmetry, the total number of roots is $\;\color{red}{63}$.

Comment: Isn't $2\times \biggl\lfloor \dfrac{50}{\pi}\biggr\rfloor=30$ ?

Comment: And the $0$ solution?

Comment: Symmetry allows to limit one's  investigations to $x>0$, but you have to count **all**  real solutions nevertheless.