# What is the number of possible $ x$ values in $\frac{x}{100}= \sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem**
 $\frac{x}{100}= \sin(x)$ We are asked to find the number of possible values of $x$ in this scenario and I had tried to figure it out by the use of trigonometric identities but then i had realized that there are no trig identities that can help me... or is there?

**steps that i had tried:**
I first multiplied 100 on both sides to get $x$ by itself to get:
$100(\sin x)=x$

Then i determined that $\sin x \le 1$ therefore I had determined that $\frac{x}{100}$ is $\le 1$

But when i look at the answer choices all of them are less than $100$ meaning that all of them are going to make $\frac{x}{100}$ less than 100 when $x$ is substituted.

Comment: @angelo mark I understand that you are a perfectionist but maybe changing all the x's into $x$ is a bit too much?

Comment: Sorry. I'll remember your username for not editing in future. Really Sorry.

Comment: This question has already been answered. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814707/how-many-solutions-has-the-equation-sin-x-fracx100/1814722#1814722).

Comment: @AngeloMark don't worry man, i do the same and win 2 points. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|\sin x|\le 1$, one needs only to consider $\frac{|x|}{100} \le 1$, or $|x|\le 100$. Since both functions are odd, we restrict ourselves to the interval $[0,100]$. The curve

$$\tag{1} y = \frac{ x}{100}$$

is positive on $(0,100]$. $\sin x$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. On each (half) period

$$[0,\pi], [2\pi, 3\pi], \cdots [2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]$$

as long as $(2n+1) \pi <100$, the curve $(1)$ intersects $\sin x$ at $2$ points. Since $15.5< 100/2\pi <16$, this means that there are $32$ nonnegative solution and thus $63$ solution in the real line.

Comment: Are you did not make any errors? because the solution choices are 61, 62, 63. 64, or 65

Comment: @JohnRawls Yes, I suck at counting.

Comment: i'm sure you are right but can u explain on how u set  15<100/2π<16 and why this means that there are 32 nonnegative solutions and 63 real solutions?

Comment: @JohnRawls : $15<100/2\pi<16$ are obtained by direct calculation (indeed I need $15.5 <100/2\pi$. This implies that there are $16$ such $[2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]$ in $[0,100]$ and each gives me $2$ solutions. Thus we have $32$ in $[0,100]$. There are also $32$ solutions in $[-100,0]$, but that $0$ is in both counting, so the total number should be $32\times 2 -1  = 63$.

Comment: Really, I just plug in $100/2\pi$ in wolfram alpha and got around 15.9.

Answer (score -1):

look at this site body must be [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F100%20%3D%20sin(x)