# Number of solutions of $\sin x= \frac x {10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The easiest way to do this is plot graphs of $10 \sin x$ and $y=x$ to find number of intersection points.

However, is there a *non graphical* solution to this problem?

**Edit:** 
My problem is different from the linked problem because the answers to that focus only on graphical solutions.

Comment: You need braces to group digits; e.g. `\frac x {10}` displays as $\frac x {10}$.

Comment: Hint: There are no solutions outside $[-10,10]$

Comment: @Henry i know that

Comment: Hint: what is the how many positive solution there are vs how many negative solutions are

Comment: See [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @Rohan not useful

Comment: @ajotatxe this method won't work, look at Basins of attraction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many solutions has the equation $\sin x= \frac{x}{100}$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814707/how-many-solutions-has-the-equation-sin-x-fracx100)

Comment: i have found six solutions

Comment: Can you apply MVT here?

Comment: What is MVT @ArchisWelankar?

Comment: MVT is MEAN VALUE THEOREM.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar how do you think to use the MVT?

Comment: Between two roots of f (x) there is atleast one root of f'(x).

Comment: @Abcd If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot solve the equation exactly but you can very well find the number of solutions.

The extrema of the function $10\sin x-x$ are found at the roots of $10\cos x-1=0$, i.e. $\pm\arccos\dfrac1{10}+2k\pi$. The values at the extrema are thus

$$\pm10\sqrt{1-\frac1{100}}\mp\arccos\frac1{10}-2k\pi.$$

As the sine is bounded by $\pm1$, by solving $\pm10-x=0$ we know that no root can arise outside $[-10,10]$. By numerical computation of the extrema in that range (with a sufficient approximation such that the signs are guaranteed exact), you spot $7$ changes of signs, hence $7$ roots.

$$\begin{matrix}x& f(x)\\\hline
-10& \ge0\\
-7.8& -2.2\\
-4.8& 14.8\\
-1.5& -8.5\\
1.5& 8.5\\
4.8& -14.8\\
7.8 &2.2\\
10& \le0\\
\end{matrix}$$

[image]

This discussion gives seven starting intervals to refine the roots by numerical methods, such as regula falsi.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note we can look only on the positive part.

Secondly we can look only at $[0,10]$

Now, how many repetitions $\sin x$ do in that time? The answer is around $1.5$

Now how parts are there in the positive part? $2$

Each part goes to some value and then return to $0$

From those things we can get that we have $4$ interactions over $x\ge 0$

Multiply it by $2$ and subtract $1$(because $0$ is solution of both cases) and you get $7$